# Page Builder- Advance Section in Row Layout

Tags: magento2

I want to add a ID field in the advance section of Row Layout in Magento 2 Pagebuilder.Here i will enter unique id for my every Row sections
Please Help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a new field in the Page Builder Advance Section of Row Layout  you can follow below steps

1. Create view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/row.xml in your custom module

   ```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
        <type name="row">
            <appearances>
                <appearance name="contained">
                    <elements>
                        <element name="inner">
                            <attribute name="custom" source="data-custom"/>
                        </element>
                     </elements>
                </appearance>
            </appearances>
        </type>
    </config>
   ```
2. Create view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_base_form.xml in your custom module

   ```
        <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
            <fieldset name="advanced" sortOrder="90">
                <field name="custom" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
                    <settings>
                        <label translate="true">Custom Field</label>
                        <dataScope>custom</dataScope>
                        <dataType>text<dataType>
                    </settings>
                </field>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
   ```

Comment: Thank you @SanthoshP. It was very helpful. :)